# Android and Web App sharing Kotlin code

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin

One of the major “selling” points of Kotlin appears to be its ability to compile both to JVM or Android and to JavaScript for the web. To make use of this, it should be possible to have a code base where some files are shared between an Android App and a browser Web App.

However, so far I found little details on *how* such a thing would be set up, in particularly when working with Android Studio and its underlying Gradle setup, starting from a a run of the Android Studio New Project Wizard. I don't mind if I can only build the Web App on the command line, but I'd like to maintain the Android debugging hookups that Android Studio provides. So far I know very little about Gradle and typical idioms for its use.

I'm sure that I'm not the first person to have this idea, so I'd like to know some best practices on how to set this up. Questions that come to my mind include the following:

- Do I mix the `kotlin2js` and the `kotlin-android` plugin in a single build file, or do I need to have multiple build files (perhaps I should say “modules” or “projects” except I don't know which)?
- If I have multiple build files, should that be two (one Android one Web) or three (one more for shared things)?

  - If it is two build files, how do I reference the shared sources?
  - If it is three build files, which plugin(s) do I use for the shared one?
- Do I need to split my sources over three different source trees? Are there any conventions how these should be called?
- Do I need to split my classes into three groups of packages, or can code for different targets coexist in the same package?
- What configuration settings do I need to tweak to make the IDE aware of the layout of my project?

I've read the following relevant documentation, among other:

- https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html
- https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/intro_multi_project_builds.html
- https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html
- https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-android.html

Comment: Just found https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multiplatform.html which appears to be the key to my question. Still need to try this out before I write it up as an answer of my own.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [IDEA wizard](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2017/12/intellij-idea-2017-3-support-for-kotlin-multi-platform-projects/) to create a simple multiplatfrom project for you (File -> New -> Project -> Kotlin -> Kotlin (Multiplatform - experimental) ). Community edition should suffice.

Answering your questions:

1. You don't mix plugins. You create a separate module for your common code and use `'kotlin-platform-common'` plugin for it.
2. Three modules, special plugin 'kotlin-platform-common'
3. Use common sense for source splitting. Put whatever you want/able to reuse in the common code. Put platform-specific code in platform modules.
4. No package restrictions. You can put everything in the same package if you so desire =)
5. Pretty sure it should just work. If not, try re-importing.